# how do I write a list of data to S3 in ORC format

Tags: python, amazon-s3, orc

I need to write a file in ORC format directly to an S3 bucket. the file will be a result of a query to a db. 
I know how to write a CSV file directly to S3 but couldn't find a way to write directly in ORC.. any recommendations?

Comment: It isn't clear whether you are asking for code to output ORC, or asking for code to write to Amazon S3. Do you currently have code that will output to ORC locally?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. i'll try to clarify  I know how to upload a file to S3 but since the code I'm writing will run in a lambda function I cannot write the file locally and then upload it. what I need is to take the query result I retrieved, process it to an ORC format and write it to S3, all done in memory. If I would have local storage I guess I would have written the file to the local storage and then simply upload it but I can't.

Comment: Why is it that you "cannot write the file locally and then upload it"? If the file is under 500MB, then you can create the file in `/tmp/` and then upload it to S3.

Comment: because the size of the file depends on the result of the query and I'm not sure I can assume its under 500MB, i'll double check that. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. [save ORC content to file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html)

using default values as per the linked documentation as there is no code sample to work with

```py
df = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/users.parquet")
df.select("name", "favorite_color").write.save("namesAndFavColors.parquet")
```

2. [upload file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-s3-s3-python-example-upload-file.py.html)

```py
import boto3


# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

filename = 'file.txt'
bucket_name = 'my-bucket'

# Uploads the given file using a managed uploader, which will split up large
# files automatically and upload parts in parallel.
s3.upload_file(filename, bucket_name, filename)
```